# Specific pythagorean triple

Tags: pythagorean-triples

A question states that $x,y,$ and $z$ are positive integers and $x^2 + 2021y^2 = z^2.$ It then proceeds to ask how many such triples $(x,y,z)$ there are. I would like to set $2021y^2 = a^2$ and than solve as a typical pythagorean triple, but I'm not sure how I should move on from there. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: $2001$ is not a perfect square so your $a$ would not be an integer.

Comment: Apologies, $2021.$ I made a typo there.

Comment: ${2021}$ is also not a perfect square

Comment: Do you know the method of finding ordinary Pythagorean triples by parametrizing the rational points on the unit circle? It generalizes to this problem.

Comment: Now your text refers to both $2021$ and $2201$. Please edit for clarity.  Note that neither of those are perfect squares

Comment: @MishaLavrov I'm afraid I don't quite remember.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Evans/Carter-2012.pdf) first :)

Comment: I can't read it due to parental controls on my computer. What does it state?

Comment: @MishaLavrov omg, this is amazing. I've never seen this harry potter story before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find one solution, $(x,y,z)$, then the answer to the question is "infinitely many," because for any positive integer $a$, $(ax,ay,az)$ will be another.

So to find one solution note that $2021 = 43\cdot 47.$  The equation can be rewritten:

$$43\cdot 47y^2 = z^2-x^2 = (z-x)(z+x).$$

$43$ and $47$ divide the left side, so they must divide the right.  We guess that  that maybe $z-x=43$ and $z+x = 47.$  This gives $z=45$, $x=2$, forcing $y=1$.  So there's the one solution.  You can probably construct others similarly.

Answer (score 1):

At least four distinct infinite families like Pythagorean triples. These are primitive, that is $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1,$ as long as $\gcd(u,v) = 1$ and we discard those additional cases, in the very first one we do not allow both $u,v$ odd for example.
$$ x = 47 u^2 - 43 v^2 \; , \; \; y = 2 u v \; , \; \;  z = 47 u^2 + 43 v^2  $$

$$ x = 2 u^2 + 90uv +2 v^2 \; , \; \; y = u^2 - v^2 \; , \; \;  z = 45 u^2 + 4uv + 45 v^2  $$

$$   x = 2 u^2 + 2uv -1010 v^2 \; , \; \; y = 2uv+v^2  \; , \; \;  z = 2 u^2 + 2uv + 1011 v^2   $$

$$   x =  u^2  -2021 v^2 \; , \; \; y = 2uv  \; , \; \;  z =  u^2 + 2021 v^2   $$

Comment: Thanks for being more ambitious than I.  It shows that the first rule of number theory is "factor".

Comment: @B.Goddard   the rule here was find positive binary quadratic forms that square to the identity form under Gauss composition, these will give the values for $z.$